# Asp.Net and External DLL

Tags: asp.net-3.5, skype

i'm writing a web application that works with an external dll (activex),
the dll was written by skype developers,

the problem is that,
in a case of any event (status changing, attachment, etc..) in the client side, a delegate needs to be call on the server side.

so when i'm changing a status in the skype program, it seem that a postback really happen but there is no affect on the client side.

for example , i'm trying to change a label content by his new value from the server side (using label that runat server) but nothing change.

i succedded to make a java script interval 
so when it recognize any changes 
it replace the content of the label.

i preffer not to use it because the dll already support that events.

thanks in advance.

Comment: silly question, but is the Skype control inside a <form runat="server"> tag?

Comment: i'm not using "skype" as as control.

it been used directly from the server side as a reference,
also from client side (as an <object>)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your problem is simulating a post-back to make the label change its contents. If so, this link might be helpful:
[Using doPostBack Function in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511358/using-dopostback-function-in-asp-net)